# Why does importing the openpyxl take so long?

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I wrote a GUI program using python tkinter and noticed it's extremely slow to start up, it took 8 seconds for the window to show up! I checked the code and finally found it's because of an Excel read/write module named *openpyxl*. When I commented out thie line: `import openpyxl`. The GUI window show up instantly.

I also tried to run code `import openpyxl` on python prompt and it nearly took 3 seconds to finish running the code!

Is this normal take so long to load this module?

PS: i'm using openpyxl 3.0.2

Comment: It's odd that it's so slow for you; for me the module imports in the order of microseconds at worst, on a computer that's over 10 years old.  (Although the timings were similar on a 2 year old laptop with SSD, so maybe the hardware isn't so important).

Comment: Yeah, it's very strange. I even tried on my personal computer, still took long seconds.

Comment: This import takes 12 seconds on my new laptop. Absurd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know outright *why* it's so slow, however I do know that it simply is. You can try using a code profiler (like in PyCharm) to find out what exactly takes so long, or you can improve user experience by importing the module at runtime whenever you need it.

Take the following:

```
import openpyxl


... gui stuff


def on_button_clicked():
    openpyxl.do_something()
    ...done
```

The following code would take ages to load up for the user, changing it to the following would drastically improve startup performance and lead to a better user experience.

Do note that at the end of the day the code would still take 3 seconds to load, but you're moving it to a place where people don't mind it to happen as they expect things to take a little longer if they press a button and a loader gets shown

```
... gui stuff


def on_button_click():
    ... show a loader or something
    import openpyxl
    openpyxl.do_something()
    ... done
```

Comment: Isn't importing on the fly a nono? Tthis way you're going to import it every tim eyou click the button. That hardly seems to be a good idea

Comment: @Kraay89 correct, it isn't best practice however you could argue that it might be worth it for the sake of user experience. If you really want to get fancy you could write a function that stores the imported modules into a dictionary and checks if they're already imported or something but that really exceeds the scope of the question

Comment: Once the module is imported it will be in `sys.modules`, so the cost of importing again should be minimal.